# Excel to JSON converter in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to parse and excel file to JSON. How can we achieve this in Angular 2. I have tried excel-as-json through npm but it is not working

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? As well as the error stacktrace? It would be a huge help for us

Comment: I have tried below code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XLSX modlue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to extract data from excel.

```js
makeJSON() {
  for(var i=0;i<execlData.length;i++) {
    if(execlData[i] && execlData[i].length > 0) {
      this.items.push({
        'param1': execlData[i][0],
        'param2': execlData[i][1],
        'param3': execlData[i][2],
        'param4': execlData[i][3],
      });
    }
  }
}

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  /* read workbook */
  const bstr: string = e.target.result;
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});

  /* grab first sheet */
  const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

  /* save data */
  let execlData = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));

  this.makeJSON(execlData);
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the transformation have to happen from the file itself to JSON? This would be much more easily handled (comparatively) as a formula in Excel to transform and output the values in Excel to JSON nodes.

Comment: Yes the transformation have to happen from file to JSON.

Comment: If you're having to open up a file, you really want to handle that server-side.  If you're intent on client-side and having issues with excel-as-json, you should post the piece you're having issues with in a question specific to that.